# SimpleDateFormat giving wrong date and time after some time of deployment

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have 2 files In my code :

File 1 Content :

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
public static final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

File 2 Content :

```
sdf.format(formatter.parse("2015-02-02")));
```

Issue : Line above in  file 2 prints "2015-02-02 12:00:00" initially for few hours , but after that it prints "2015-02-01 06:00:00" .
Any idea what could be the issue here.

Additional info : 
My server is running on some cloud machine  located in US .
`new java.util.Date( )` gives UTC timezone value correctly all the time.
Server is started using command `java -jar xyz.jar`.
There are other files which are using `sdf` and `formatter` variables.
I am unable to reproduce this  on local machine.
Once the issue starts happening on servers, it shows wrong date time until server is restarted.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is poorly designed and notoriously troublesome. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Was this peculiar behaviour observed once or how many times approximately? Can you reproduce it systematically?

Comment: @OleV.V. I cannot reproduce it locally .Once the issue starts happening on servers , it shows wrong date time until server is restarted.Used DateTimeFormatter and it fixed the issue.

Comment: @OleV.V. I apologize for the  confusion here . I had used hh:mm:ss in my code which was showing time in 12 hours format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the official Oracle documentation, it says that

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create
>   separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access
>   a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

By looking at your code, you seem to be reusing the same instance across multiple threads. That is incorrect!!!

Either maintain a pool of formatters OR synchronize the access (not recommended) OR you can create a new instance every time.

Comment: Or better, use the new api, which has a threadsafe formatter.

Comment: Aptly said Nathan.

Comment: //api start ->
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
sdf.format(formatter.parse("2015-02-02 ")));
//api end ->

creating new instance as above also gives the same output ? Anything wrong with this ? @CuriousMind

Comment: @Ajay depends how slow you want your server to be.

Comment: @NathanHughes `DateTimeFormatter` is not only thread-safe, as you already said, it is also immutable. Any piece of code can alter the time zone of a `SimpleDateFormat`, another potential explanation for the observed behaviour. No such trick possible with `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

The comments by Nathan Hughes and myself are good enough to be combined into an answer: Use java.time, the modern date time API, and specifically its `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter printFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Now your formatting may for example go like this:

```
    String stringToPrint = LocalDate.parse("2015-02-02")
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .format(printFormatter);

    System.out.println(stringToPrint);
```

This prints:

> 2015-02-02 00:00:00

In the format conversion code I am taking advantage of the fact that your original string, `2015-02-02`, is in the standard ISO 8601 format for a date. `LocalDate` parses this format as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter.

### What went wrong in your code?

It would seem from your question that there are two likely explanations for the behaviour you have observed:

1. One of the other classes of the program on the server that uses the two formatters, sets the time zone of one of them, for example to America/Chicago.
2. Two or more threads use the formats simultaneously, which causes one of them to behave incorrectly.

The observed behaviour, an error of 6 hours, where after it has turned up, it continues until server restart, seems more consistent with the first explanation, which you also confirmed in your own answer, and thank you for doing that.

Contrary to `SimpleDateFormat` the modern `DateTimeFormatter` is thread-safe, which prevents any thread problems, and immutable, which prevents other classes from modifying the formatter. So it solves your problem in both cases.

As an aside, I think you are aware of your incorrect use of lowercase `hh` in the format pattern string. `hh` is for hour within AM or PM from 01 through 12, whereas you need uppercase `HH` for hour of day from 00 through 23 (this goes both for `SimpleDateFormat` and for `DateTimeFormatter`).

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

Timezone was getting set for `sdf` by some piece of code in another api , which was causing the issue.Here is sample example to replicate the issue locally :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class SimpleDateFormatTExample {

private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
private static String timeZone = "CST";

public static void main(String[] args) {


    //-Duser.timezone=UTC


    try {
        String dateTimeString1 = sdf.format(formatter.parse("2018-01-01"));
        System.out.println("Thread Main->> " + dateTimeString1);
//output : Thread Main->> 2018-01-01 12:00:00

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            //timezone is changed by another thread
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
            String dateTimeString = sdf.format(formatter.parse("2018-01-01"));
            System.out.println("Thread child->> " + dateTimeString);
//output : Thread child->> 2017-12-31 06:00:00
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();


    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        String dateTimeString1 = sdf.format(formatter.parse("2018-02-15"));
        System.out.println("Thread Main:After timezone changes by another thread->> " + dateTimeString1);
//output : Thread Main:After timezone changes by another thread->> 2018-02-14 06:00:00

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}